# Can't get log4j2 to backup to file

Tags: java, logging, console, log4j2

I'm trying to get a log4j2 to write to both the console and a file at the same time.

I'm following an example specified [here](https://dzone.com/articles/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file)

The write to the console is working, but I'm getting an empty log file. Here are the contents of log4j2.properties:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=logs/backupRestore.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=guru.springframework.blog.log4j2properties
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `logile` in `appenderRefs` and also add `appenderRef`

```
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout,logfile
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.logfile.ref=LOGFILE
```